# Change the step size of Highcharts Drag?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to change the step size of dragging with Highcharts. For example, when I have data with large values (in the thousands), it is pretty unclean to be dragging values and getting random numbers like 4327. What I would like to be able to do is round the dragging values off to a certain point based on the max value of the y-scale, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. So in this case, the dragging would go from 4300 to 4400, as opposed to getting random numbers inbetween. Here is a JS fiddle that demonstrates the unnecessary digits I am getting when dragging:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utnz2b9e/28/)

```
var planChart; 

$(function () {
planChart = {
    chart: {

        animation: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true,
    },
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: '#20709e'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'title',
            style: {
                color: '#20709e'
            }
        },
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {

                    drag: function (e) {
                        // Returning false stops the drag and drops. Example:
                        /*
                        if (e.newY > 300) {
                            this.y = 300;
                            return false;
                        }
                        */


                    },
                    drop: function () {  }
                }
            },
            stickyTracking: false
        },
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        },
        line: {
            cursor: 'ns-resize'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'title',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> <b> {point.y} </b><br/>'
        },
        data: [7042, 40494, 48204, 20383, 20938, 4803, 23903, 22, 23939, 13032, 1332, 93932],
        //draggableX: true,
        draggableY: true,
       dragMinY: 0,
        style: {
            color: '#20709e'
        }
    }]
}
$('.actualPlansPlot').highcharts(planChart);
 });

$(document).on('click', '#updateYScale', function(e) {
    var yValue = $('#newYValue')[0].value;
    planChart.yAxis[0].max = yValue;
    $('.actualPlansPlot').highcharts(planChart);
})
```

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/draggable-points/master/draggable-points.js?1"></script>
<div class="actualPlansPlot" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<input id="newYValue" type="number" />
<button id="updateYScale">Update Scale</button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can catch [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) and call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) to adapt range to your own preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
tooltip: {
     shared: true,
     formatter: function () {
           return  this.x + '<br/><b>' + Math.ceil(this.y/100)*100 + '</b>';
     }
},
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/utnz2b9e/31/)

Comment: Thank you, this ended up working really well, I accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change value of a point, then you could change `filterRange` function of draggable-points plugin to filter points values. E.g. add `dragPrecision` option that will change returned point value.

```
function filterRange(newY, series, XOrY) {
    var options = series.options,
        dragMin = pick(options['dragMin' + XOrY], undefined),
        dragMax = pick(options['dragMax' + XOrY], undefined),
        precision = pick(options['dragPrecision'], undefined);

    if(!isNaN(precision)) {
        newY = Math.round(newY / precision) * precision;
    }

    if (newY < dragMin) {
        newY = dragMin;
    } else if (newY > dragMax) {
        newY = dragMax;
    }
    return newY;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8wbn5no/

Other way, that will not require editing the plugin, is to change how point's update in Highcharts is working through wrapping `Point.prototype.update` function.

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'update', function (proceed, options) {
        var filter = 100,
            filteredY = options && options.y;
        if(!isNaN(filteredY)) {
            arguments[1].y = Math.round(filteredY / filter) * filter;
        }
        // Run original proceed method
        proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdvswdsw/